# Image url not found in html

Tags: python, html, django

I have some images stored in my Django DB. And I am trying to display all of them on my web.

Python file

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        result = Video.objects.all()
        return render(request, "videos/index.html", {
            "data": result
        })
```

HTML file

```
{% for x in data %}
  <div class="content">
    <img src="{{ x.image }}">
    <h3>{{ x.title }}</h3>
    <h3>{{ x.user }}</h3>
    <video
      class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"
      controls="controls"
    >
      <source src="{{ x.video.url }}" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  </div>
  <br />
{% endfor %}
```

Surprisingly, the video is loading, but the image isn't. When I opened the source code on the browser

```
<img src(unknown)>
```

this is what I see.

Comment: I have also tried {{ x.image.url }}

Comment: It's hard to say for sure without knowing what the structure of `x` is but if I must hazard a guess it's most probably because of invalid characters in the url or `x.image` isn't a string or something similar.

Comment: Got it man. Actually in my models I had stored image by the name thumbnail and overhere I was trying {{ x.image }} instead of {{ x.thumbnail }}